# Why Ganesh Chaturthi celebrated during rainy season?

Tags: festivals, ganesha

I know Ganesh Chaturthi festival celebrated with huge idols etc. So why choosing **rainy season** which will be problematic while celebrating?

Comment: "So why choosing rainy season".. it is not choosing.. Lord Ganesha manifested himself on Bhadra Shukla Chaturthi... and now you think since it is rainy season let's shift his birthday?..

Comment: Becauase Shastras say so :)